# Do the bounds change when multiplying a probability distribution by a constant?

Tags: probability, statistics

Do the bounds change when multiplying a probability distribution by a constant? For example consider when an exponential distribution bounded by upper bound A, lower bound B and mean X, is multiplied by a constant C. What changes can one expect to the upper and lower bound?

Comment: The question is quite unclear. What does it mean to multiply a probability distribution by a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean?: $\mathsf P(a\leq X\leq b) = \mathsf P(a\,c\leq Y\leq b\,c)$ when $Y=c\,X$ in general, and, for an exponential distribution in particular:

$$\int_a^b \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\operatorname d x = \int_{ac}^{bc} \frac \lambda c\cdot e^{-\lambda y/c}\operatorname d y \quad\text{where } X\sim\mathcal{Exp}(\lambda), Y\sim\mathcal{Exp}(\lambda/c)$$
and such?

Comment: Exactly.. So I take from this the bounds are multiplied by the constant?

Comment: @aman1230 Exactly